# Online Meetings

Tags: remote-access, meetings

We have a board meeting that goes on every Friday of the week. The online meeting room is booked for that but we want to run another meeting at the same time when the board meeting is running but we can't and we are using GoTo Meetings.

Could someone suggest any online meeting platforms where we can run 2 meetings at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean or not but I believe Zoom recently added the ability for you to be in 2 meetings at once.

Answer (score 1):

BigBlueButton.  Both Free and free, you can self-host or pay one of several hosting companies to host it for you.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of alternatives that let you freely run meetings without installing the hosting software are:

- [join.me](https://www.join.me/) - Windows and Mac only.
- [jitsi](https://meet.jit.si/) - Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Comment: Another alternative https://whereby.com